# wpf custom control not show validation error

Tags: wpf, xaml

Validation error will not show if I transfer Binding through Dependency Property in custom control.

**DETAIL**

I have a viewmodel which always have a validation error on one property

```
class ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get { return "Error"; }
    }
}
```

and a `TextBox` on view

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding Value, 
        Mode=TwoWay, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
        NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
```

so it will be surrounded by a red border.

[image: ui picture]

Then I created a custom control named `WrappedTextBox` which contains a `Text` Dependency Property

```
class WrappedTextBox : Control
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(WrappedTextBox));
}
```

and template

```
<Style TargetType="local:WrappedTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:WrappedTextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <TextBox
                            Text="{Binding Text, 
                                Mode=TwoWay, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

put it on view

```
<local:WrappedTextBox
    Text="{Binding Value, 
        Mode=TwoWay, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
        NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
```

as the picture above shows, the second control has no red border on it.

if I don't remove `Validation.ErrorTemplate` of `WrappedTextBox`, it will be

[image: picture 2]

How do I show error template on `TextBox` inside `WrappedTextBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know your problem is that `IDataErrorInfo` needs to be implemented on the class you are binding to, in your `ControlTemplate` you are binding to the `Text`-Property of your `WrappedTextBox`, therefore your `WrappedTextBox` itself has to implement `IDataErrorInfo` to make validation work on your `TextBox`.

Read also this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview) what you also can do instead of creating a new control.

For what you want to achieve 2 options came to my mind (**Note**: This options are created under the assumption that you are doing more stuff so the options of the previously mentioned article does not apply to you)

**Option 1**: Derive direct from `TextBox`

Code behind:

```
class WrappedTextBox : TextBox
{

}
```

Style:

```
<Style TargetType="local:WrappedTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                </AdornerDecorator>
                <-- ControlTemplate.Triggers etc. -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage: (same as before)

```
<local:WrappedTextBox
    Text="{Binding Value, 
        Mode=TwoWay, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
        NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
```

**Option 2**: Pass the `Binding` itself

Code behind:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_TEXTBOX", Type = typeof(TextBox))]
class WrappedTextBox : Control
{
    private TextBox _partTextBox;

    private BindingBase _textBinding;
    public BindingBase TextBinding
    {
        get => _textBinding;
        set
        {
            if (_textBinding != value)
            {
                _textBinding = value;
                ApplyTextBinding();
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _partTextBox = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_TEXTBOX") as TextBox;
        ApplyTextBinding();
    }

    private void ApplyTextBinding()
    {
        if (_partTextBox != null)
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(_partTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty, _textBinding);
    }
}
```

Style:

```
<Style TargetType="local:WrappedTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:WrappedTextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TEXTBOX" />
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<local:WrappedTextBox
    TextBinding="{Binding Value, 
        Mode=TwoWay, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
        NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
```